# Start Approval Process on multiple items

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, approval-process, approval, ms-flow

I am trying to send single mail notification on multiple list item created in SharePoint List at same time,  if approver is the same for all newly created items in a SharePoint List.
The SharePoint list is given below image:-
[image]

Also I would like to add, both item details in the body of "Start and wait for an approval" in Power Automate.

The result that i would like is shown below:-

[image]

Please, provide some assistance.
Thanks

Comment: You can create a mechanism for approval workflow in Power Automate. And to send emails same as provided above, you can use actionable cards concept. Reference link: https://d365demystified.com/2020/11/23/adaptive-cards-for-outlook-actionable-messages-using-power-automate-power-platform/

Comment: Have you thought of the possibility of what would happen if the approver would want to reject one of the two applications? 
By pressing approve or reject this means that both applications (or three or four or more) are approved or rejected.

Comment: Yes, there is no need to approve/ reject one of two  application. I would like to approve/ reject the multiple application with  getting multiple item details in mail body, that have been created at same time.